# pop/shift a ruby array multiple times

Tags: ruby, arrays

My code currently looks like this

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def pop_three
  pop = []
  3.times { pop << numbers.pop }
  return pop
end
```

Is there any way to do what's inside the `pop_three` method in one line?

I basically want to do something like `numbers.slice(0, 3)` but deleting the array items that are in the slice.

Uhm...hrmmm, I think I just realized I can try slice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes

```
numbers.pop(3)
```

Or

```
numbers.shift(3)
```

If you want this other side.

Comment: Interesting, wonder when they added that. The docs I have don't mention any parameters.

Comment: you could have added the `shift` one to pass the limit ;-)

Comment: @brand I didn't read the doc. Just tried. Sometimes Ruby act as expected ;-)

Comment: `Array#pop|shift` accepts parameters since Ruby 1.8.7. See for instance RubySpec ( https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/array/pop_spec.rb#L68 ).

Comment: Here's the updated link since these specs are now under the github/ruby repo (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/spec/ruby/core/array/pop_spec.rb#L61) @Marc-AndréLafortune

Answer (score 0):

what about `numbers.slice(x.size-3,3).reverse`